# Python wxWidgets : Adding components to a Panel fires an wxWindowBase::AddChild(): AddChild() called twice assertion on Windows

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a GUI that has a frame, and I'm trying to put the main content into a Panel, adding components to it using absolute positioning.  This is working on Linux, however when I run it on Windows there is an assert firing stating that:

```
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "!GetChildren().Find((wxWindow*)child)" failed at ..\..\src\common\wincmn.cpp(945) in wxWindowBase::AddChild(): AddChild() called twice
```

This is triggered by the first component I add to the panel.  So my question is how to fix this, and why this problem doesn't happen on Linux?

Thanks for any help.

```
"""
Defines the main GUI panel for the app.
"""
import wx

class MainGuiPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, size):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=size)
        self.SetMinSize(size)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        self.createGui()

    def createGui(self):
        """
        Create controls on the main panel UI.  We use fixed positioning over layout managers as it gives a cleaner looking result.
        """
        x = 7
        y = 8
        self.AddChild(wx.StaticText(self, -1, "PV Power" , wx.Point(x, y)))
        self.pvPowerTF = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "0 kW", wx.Point(x + 105, y - 2), wx.Size(100, 20), style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.AddChild(self.pvPowerTF)

        y += 28
        self.AddChild(wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Load Power" , wx.Point(x, y)))
        self.loadPowerTF = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "0 kW", wx.Point(x + 105, y - 2), wx.Size(100, 20), style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.AddChild(self.loadPowerTF)

        y += 28
        self.AddChild(wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Generator Power" , wx.Point(x, y)))
        self.generatorPowerTF = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1, "0 kW", wx.Point(x + 105, y - 2), wx.Size(100, 20), style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.AddChild(self.generatorPowerTF)


    def on_paint(self, event):
        """
        Paint the background with a slight gradient
        """
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        x = 0
        y = 0
        w, h = self.GetSize()
        dc.GradientFillLinear((x, y, w, h), 'white', 'light grey', nDirection = wx.SOUTH)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must never call `AddChild()` yourself as explicitly mentioned in [the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#abf60159278059a5bb397eb8647227bb3).

You also should be aware of the fact that using absolute positions is a pretty bad idea which flat out never works in practice, especially when using pixels (and not dialog units).